# How to make sure that /taxonomy/term/24/WHATEVER gives 404?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, uri

Google found up some weird links on my website and has started indexing stuff like `/taxonomy/term/24/WHATEVER`. I don't want that.

I also don't want to find all these URLs manually, ideally they will turn up in Google Webmaster's list of broken links and I can fix them using that list.

Unfortunately in the taxonomy term view at PAGE SETTINGS it just says `Path: /taxonomy/term/%`. Is there a good way to respond 404 on `/taxonomy/term/24/WHATEVER` addresses?

Comment: This comes up every couple of months but I can't find the other posts at the moment - it's how Drupal's path system works; anything in a folder under  `a/valid/path` is considered to be that path. So `a/valid/path/foo`, `a/valid/path/bar`, etc, are all considered valid paths, even if there isn't a route explicitly defined for it, so you won't get a 404. As I understand it, that's not easy or even possible to change without a fair number of changes to core code (but might be wrong).

Comment: I think I answered one of those questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Rabbit Hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) module.

From its page:

> Rabbit Hole is a module that adds the ability to control what should
>   happen when an entity is being viewed at its own page.
>
> This works by providing multiple options to control what should happen
>   when the entity is being viewed at its own page. You have the ability
>   to
>
> - Deliver an access denied page.
> - ***Deliver a page not found page***.
> - Issue a page redirect to any path or external url.
> - Or simply display the entity (regular behavior).
>
> **Supported entities**
>
> The currently supported entities are:
>
> - Nodes
> - ***Taxonomy terms***
> - Users
> - Files

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar, but there might be some edge cases where this solution might not be suitable.

You can use [hook_taxonomy_term_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.api.php/function/hook_taxonomy_term_view/7.x) and within that check if the amount of arguments in the URL (`$_GET['q']`) is more than three.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_taxonomy_term_view().
 */
function custom_module_taxonomy_term_view($term, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if (count(arg()) > 3) {
    // This will throw a 404.
    drupal_not_found();
  }
}
```